# Fortran and C++: Linking error in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, fortran, unresolved-external

System: Windows-7-64-bit/Visual-Studio-2010/Intel-Visual-Fortran-11.

I am creating 32-bit executables.

Fortran routine declaration

```
SUBROUTINE LA01BD(N,M,L,A,B,C,X,F,IA,IPRINT,IND,WK,IER)
  !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::LA01BD
  !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES STDCALL,REFERENCE,ALIAS:"LA01BD"::LA01BD
  use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING
```

C++ function signature declaration

```
extern "C" {void __stdcall LA01BD(int *N, int *M, int *L, double *A, double *B, double *C, double *X, double *F, int *IA, int *IPRINT, int *IND, double *WK, int *IER); }
```

I created the dll from fortran code using Visual Studio 2010 and Intel Visual Fortran compiler 11. I checked the exported symobol in dependency walker and the Function is "LA01BD".

When using the same dll (the .lib file during linking) in my C++ project, I get the following linker error.

```
lpwrap.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _LA01BD@52
```

I am unable to resolve this issue. What does suffix "@52" does? How to fix the linking issue?

Thanks.

Comment: The suffix @52 means it has 13 parameters.  Try removing the alias, see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Yes, getting rid of the alias is a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ compiler applies *name decoration* to the identifier.  The __stdcall decoration is a leading _underscore and a trailing @n where n is the size of the activation frame.

The ALIAS directive in your Fortran code caused this problem, you forced it to be exported as "LA01BD" instead of "_LA01BD@52".  You should first try to remove it so the normal name decoration is applied.  If that's not an option then you'll need to either create an import library with lib.exe /def from a properly crafted .def file or fallback to late binding with GetProcAddress().

Comment: I removed it (the entire line containing the alias), but am still getting the same error.

Comment: Are you actually linking the import library?  Look what's inside of it with Dumpbin.exe /all.  And delete delete the entire line, just the ALIAS.

Comment: I removed __stdcall from my declaration in the .h file and it worked.

Comment: That's because you deleted the entire line instead of just ALIAS.

Comment: Thanks. I only have the DLLEXPORT attribute now. I got rid of everything else and it works (the build succeeds).

Comment: Well, can't argue with success.  Please close your question by marking it answered.

Comment: I marked your response as the answer. The build succeeds and the dll works as intended.

Answer (score 2):

If you must use the STDCALL calling convention, then add the DECORATE attribute to the Fortran side to instruct the compiler to decorate the specified alias.

```
SUBROUTINE LA01BD(N,M,L,A,B,C,X,F,IA,IPRINT,IND,WK,IER)
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::LA01BD
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES STDCALL,REFERENCE,ALIAS:"LA01BD"::LA01BD
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DECORATE :: LA01BD
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't knew that.

Answer (score 0):

it is caused by name mangling, please ref [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) for details. I guess you missed the extern "c" in your C++ project.

Comment: I did use extern "C" when declaring the fortran function in the header file.